# Action Script select XML element with ':' symbol on tag name

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I'm working with the Livestream API, and I need to get some XML with the desired channel info, so i'm having problem when reading the XML values with the XML object, because the tags are have the ':' symbol in the tag name, like this:

```
<ls:isLive>true</ls:isLive>
```

When I try to select like this, it obviously return me a parsing error:

```
xmlData.ls:isLive
```

And then I tried this way, but it returned me empty value:

```
xmlData["ls:isLive"]
```

How can I select this element's value by the tag name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your xml looks like this:

```
var xml:XML = <root xmlns:ls="http://blabla.com">
                 <ls:isLive>true</ls:isLive>
              </root>
```

To access `isLive` tag you need to declare [Namespace](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Namespace.html):

```
var ls:Namespace = new Namespace("ls","http://blabla.com") ;
var isLiveTag:* = xml.ls::isLive;
```

Comment: I was pretty sure this issue was due to my inexperience with XML, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a xml namespace.
In the xml header should be a definition like

```
xmlns:ls='http://someuri/schema'
```

You need to define a namespace and access the node with the namespace

I think this post will help:
[xml and namespace](http://lab.revoke.ca/2009/05/as3-xml-namespace/)

Comment: Thanks for the great link, I'm inexperienced with XML and it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure  is what you are trying to access.. i tried using that tag but as3 is giving me an error.

I think you are accessing a wrong element name.

Names should be short and simple, like this:  not like this: .

Avoid "-" characters. If you name something "first-name," some software may think you want to subtract name from first.

Avoid "." characters. If you name something "first.name," some software may think that "name" is a property of the object "first."

Avoid ":" characters. Colons are reserved to be used for something called namespaces (more later).